# Can't get VS Code Stylelint extension to lint in .ts files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, styled-components, vscode-extensions, stylelint

I'm setting up a React project with TypeScript and Styled Components from scratch. I've already done this before and in the previous project the [VS Code Stylelint extension](https://github.com/shinnn/vscode-stylelint) worked great.

However, in my new project I can't get it to work in `.ts` or `.tsx` files. It still does work in `.js` files. My setup is exactly the same as my previous project so I'm really confused about why it isn't working.

I've already opened [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85130) in the VS Code Github repo but it got closed immediately. The extension itself has disabled the possibility of opening any issues.

Some screenshots to illustrate my point:

Stylelint that works in a `.js` file
[image: Stylelint that works in a .js file]

Stylelint that doesn't work in a `.ts` file
[image: Stylelint that doesn't work in a .ts file]

Stylelint that works in a `.ts` file in another project
[image: Stylelint that works in a .ts file in another project]

Please let me know if you need any more information about my configuration or about any stuff. Any help is greatly appreciated

**EDIT:** it looks like the author has deleted the extension..

Comment: Darn... this sucks. I just came looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> EDIT: it looks like the author has deleted the extension..

The [stylelint VS Code extension](https://github.com/stylelint/vscode-stylelint) is now maintained by the [stylelint organisation](https://github.com/stylelint). It is [freely available from the Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint) and from the extensions sidebar within VSCode.

It [supports](https://github.com/stylelint/vscode-stylelint#usage) the language indentifers of:

- TypeScript (`typescript`)
- TypeScript React (`typescriptreact`)

Comment: To clarify, in VS Code config add: `"stylelint.validate": ["typescript", "typescriptreact", ...]` The default is: `"stylelint.validate": ["css", "postcss"]`